MAUI command within CollectionView requires xaml to be hot reloaded in order to work
I can't find no one online having the same trouble i'm having.
Building a pretty straightforward test app (coming from XF, checking out how MAUI is hanging), I'm coding a to-do. Within CollectionView, I have a checkbox:
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:ToDoTask">
            ...
            
            <input:CheckBox
                IsChecked="{Binding FinishedAt, Converter={StaticResource IsNotNullConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                CheckChangedCommand="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:ToDoViewModel}}, Path=FinishTaskCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                Margin="0,0,10,0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

And that works. Except it only works after I comment any portion of xaml, save, uncomment and save again - triggering a reload.
Before that it simply does not trigger the command:
[RelayCommand]
private void FinishTask(ToDoTask task)
{
    if (task == null)
        return;

    task.FinishedAt = task.FinishedAt == null
         ? DateTime.Now
         : null;
}

My BindingContext on the code-behind is set correctly and I even builder.Services.AddTransient<ToDoViewModel>() on MauiProgram.cs. I also did this:
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    if (BindingContext is ToDoViewModel viewModel)
    {
        viewModel.AppearingCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}

You can guess why. It only works after forcing a hot reload. Also, my good old pal InvalidateLayout() does not seem to have been brought over to MAUI.
Check it live: https://imgur.com/a/LDURK6W
Thank you.

What is mdc:IconButton , is it a custom control?? coming form another library?

Yeah, Material Components. Updated the question with a different control implementation.. just for clarity.

is it possible to provide definition of collectionview? It's really hard to know what's going wrong without seeing the whole thing.

Are you using any behaviors or visualstatemanagers within your CollectionView? I've experienced using <VisualStateManager/> in a CollectionView will break hot reload for some reason. When wrapping it in a comment, hot reload works again. VisualStudio often alerts that "The member [memberName] is not recognized or not accessible" while running in debug mode, underlining said property in XAML. I think it's just bugged because the XAML works fine in release.

Updated the question with the CollectionView definition. Not using any VisualStateManager.

Have you tried setting x:DataType?

@JoséPauloOliveiraFilho Before that it simply does not trigger the command: are you sure of this?? If  you put a debug point at the start of the command ... it never hits?? Also provide what's happening in IsNotNullConverter or where is this coming from.

@StephenQuan x:DataType="vm:ToDoViewModel" is on ContentPage definition.

@BhavaneshN exactly. It never hits. IsNotNullConverter is a converter from the Community Toolkit for MAUI.

I reiterate, you may need to set x:DataType for CheckChangedCommand. You will probably have more luck if you were to set a TwoWay binding on your IsChecked binding instead and react to property changed events in your view model.

Also you may need to supply the implementation of input:CheckBox
